# Deleting a feed and all activities - some activities remain

Tags: getstream-io

Our system is set up for users to create and assign tasks to themselves and others. Each user has a notification feed that follows feeds of tasks which they are assigned or involved with.

When we delete tasks we also want the task feed and all activities to be deleted. We are deleting feeds like so:

```
$client   = new GetStream\Stream\Client($client, $secret);
$taskFeed = $client->feed("task", 1234);
$taskFeed->delete();
```

However, when I look at the data explorer I still see activities related to the task in the notification feeds.

Unfollowing everyone from the task feed doesn't seem possible; the docs seem to suggest a limit of retrieving 500 followers.

What's the proper way to handle this? Do I need to remove every activity individually using the `foreign_id`s?

Comment: I also have the same scenario. How did you manage to delete all notification of a `task` from *all follower's notification feeds*?

Comment: I've been in communication with the team at Stream and they've informed me that there's a bug in their system which will be rectified sometime this week. I'll update the question after I've heard back and tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting a feed won't remove the activities that were previously added to it. They may have been replicated into other feeds via following relationships or targeting via the 'to' field.

You're correct that [removing activities](https://getstream.io/docs/ruby/#removing-activities) by `foreign_id` is the way to go.